# Pip update is failing in terminal because Anaconda is up to date - idle is not

Tags: python, macos

I am attempting to update pip for IDLE (Python 3.5) on mac using the terminal.

It tells me that pip is up to date in anaconda:

Daniels-MacBook-Pro-3:~ danielsellers$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Daniels-MacBook-Pro-3:~ danielsellers$

But IDLE is recommending I update pip, which I am inclined to do because it keeps crashing while trying to install modules.

How do I update the version of pip which IDLE is running? I'm somewhat new to python, thanks in advance

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Anaconda you are fine, if you don't uninstall it. Systems get very confused on what you want to update/use so just pick one and use it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know commands of MAC but concept should be like this:
from terminal change directory to your Python3.5 interpreter and then go in folder called Scripts. For example:

```
cd C:\Python35\Scripts
```

Then update your pip from there like:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

EDIT:

In PyCharm IDLE it is in File/Settings/Project:'project_name'/Project Interpreter. In other IDLEs should be similar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, as Anaconda is kind of inconvenient to use compared to IDLE. Now I just need to figure out what the path Python 3.5 is...

Comment: @WizardGeneral, that is eas. You can look your current interpreter path in your IDLE. Look to my edit.